# Libgdx & RoboVM to app store

Tags: java, ios, xcode, libgdx, robovm

I can compile and run my game using LibGDX 0.9.9 and RoboVM 0.0.7

I have been able to build an `ipa` for app store submission. Uploading my app with Application Loader, I get an error saying: `This bundle is invalid. Apple is currently not accepting applications built with this version of Xcode.`

Adding

```
<key>DTXcode</key>
<string>0502</string>

<key>DTXcodeBuild</key>
<string>5A3005</string>
```

to my info.plist, I get the same app store submission error.

I have tried compiling my project with every combination of the following libraries

```
LibGDX 0.9.9
LibGDX Nightly - 02/13/14

RoboVM 0.0.8
RoboVM 0.0.9
RoboVM 0.0.10-SNAPSHOT
```

With any version of RoboVM greater than 0.0.7, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No @Marshaler found for parameter 1 of @Callback method <com.badlogic.gdx.backends.iosrobovm.objectal.AVAudioPlayerDelegate$Callbacks: void didFinishPlaying(com.badlogic.gdx.backends.iosrobovm.objectal.AVAudioPlayerDelegate,org.robovm.objc.Selector,org.robovm.cocoatouch.foundation.NSObject,boolean)>
    at org.robovm.compiler.MarshalerLookup.findMarshalerMethod(MarshalerLookup.java:167)
    at org.robovm.compiler.BroMethodCompiler.getParameterType(BroMethodCompiler.java:492)
    at org.robovm.compiler.BroMethodCompiler.getBridgeOrCallbackFunctionType(BroMethodCompiler.java:513)
    at org.robovm.compiler.BroMethodCompiler.getCallbackFunctionType(BroMethodCompiler.java:505)
    at org.robovm.compiler.CallbackMethodCompiler.callback(CallbackMethodCompiler.java:78)
    at org.robovm.compiler.CallbackMethodCompiler.compileCallback(CallbackMethodCompiler.java:107)
    at org.robovm.compiler.CallbackMethodCompiler.doCompile(CallbackMethodCompiler.java:74)
    at org.robovm.compiler.AbstractMethodCompiler.compile(AbstractMethodCompiler.java:74)
    at org.robovm.compiler.ClassCompiler.callbackMethod(ClassCompiler.java:1070)
    at org.robovm.compiler.ClassCompiler.compile(ClassCompiler.java:566)
    at org.robovm.compiler.ClassCompiler.compile(ClassCompiler.java:283)
    at org.robovm.compiler.AppCompiler.compile(AppCompiler.java:198)
    at org.robovm.compiler.AppCompiler.compile(AppCompiler.java:216)
    at org.robovm.compiler.AppCompiler.main(AppCompiler.java:438)
```

I'm at a loss. I just want to submit my app to the Apple App Store. RoboVM 0.0.7 doesn't seem to work and I can't compile my project with any newer version of RoboVM. Let me know if you need any more information.

How can I submit my app using RoboVM 0.0.7 (emulate Xcode 5.2)?

or

How can I fix my error and compile with >0.0.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bundle is invalid` problem was fixed in RoboVM 0.0.9 so you must use at least that version. The cause of the `No @Marshaler found` error is probably because you have an old version of `robovm-cocoatouch.jar` in your classpath somewhere. Make sure you only have jars from RoboVM 0.0.9 in your Eclipse classpath.

Comment: I'm using Intellij IDEA. I changed the resources to use the newer libraries, but the jar artifact I compile was still using the 0.0.7 libraries.